# Как включить привилегию? Windows 7

Tags: windows

Я выдаю пользователю привилегию SeDebugPrivelege, затем от лица пользователя в cmd пишу whoami /priv, но мне не показывает в списке привилегий SeDebugPrivelege, есть всякие SeUndockPrivelege, а SeDebugPrivelege нет, делаю вывод, что она выключена. Как включить привилегию, если она уже выдана пользователю? Желательно без использования кода, а как-нибудь вручную.